# How to initialize and return an object in a single line

Tags: javascript, typescript, lambda, object-initialization

I am trying to create Option objects based on the following typed interface:

```
interface Option {
    /** Text for rendering */
    label: string;
    /** Value for searching */
    value: string | number;
    /**
     * Allow this option to be cleared
     * @default true
     */
    clearableValue?: boolean;
}
```

Is it possible to convert the following to a single line?

```
const options = [1, 2, 3].map<Option>((t) => {
    const option: Option = { label: String(t), value: String(t) };
    return option;
});
```

I tried:

```
const options = [1, 2, 3].map<Option>((t) => Option = { label: String(t), value: String(t) });
```

but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there:

```
const options = [1, 2, 3].map(t => <Option>{ label: String(t), value: String(t) });
```

Type assertion `<Option>{ label: String(t), value: String(t) }` can also be done with `as` operator: `t => ({ label: String(t), value: String(t) }) as Option`

**Update**: As you've already figured out - the first option (`<Option>`) creates ambiguity in **.tsx* files, so `as` syntax is preferred.

Comment: The first suggestion has an error: "Symbol 'label' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module". Is it normal? I am using TypeScript 1.8. The second suggestion works fine.

Comment: Try to put object initializer into brackets `<Option>({ label: String(t), value: String(t) })` . (It works fine without in TS 2)

Comment: No it doesn't help. Maybe this wasn't supported before TS2. Unless there is a way to make it work, you could update your reply to differentiate between the two versions and I'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: Indeed, it seems due to the fact that I am in a *.tsx file and <Option> as an element returned from a function is conflicting with HTML-like elements (it works fine with *.ts). Do you know how to escape it?

Comment: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/genericTSX.html

Comment: A bit hackish, there doesn't seem to be a good solution. If you can update your answer to reflect that it'll probably save some time to people.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a typescript [cast](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/release-notes/typescript-1.6.html):

```
const options = [1, 2, 3].map<Option>((t) => <Option>{ label: String(t), value: String(t) } );
```

Comment: This triggers an error: "Symbol 'label' cannot be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module". Is it normal? I am using TypeScript 1.8.

Comment: I tried it in the typescript playground without any errors. I am sorry that this obviously does not work in your environment.